# Which filesystem is this volume, I want to mount to an ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, hard-drive

See those images below, it shows errors like wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, missing codepage or helper program, or other error....
I just tried to mount it as FAT

`mount /dev/sdf /home/ubuntu/sdf -t vfat`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you create the filesystem? Why not check the system this volume came from? You can try running `$ file /dev/sdf` to see if `file` can figure out what filesystem it is.

Comment: @EEAA no, it does not show the filesystem...

Comment: Perhaps you need to mount a **partition**, not the raw disk device?

Comment: What's the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdf` ?

Comment: That was inside the fist image:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/bApWP.png

Comment: @EEAA I think I can only mount the raw disk in Amazon EC2

Answer (score 5):

You get the error message you are seeing when you specify the wrong fs type to the mount command.

If you created a filesystem on the disk then you should use the same type in the mount command. If you don't know what the fstype is then you can try the `auto` option

```
mount -t auto /dev/sdf /mnt
```

and then you can use df -T to find the type

```
Filesystem             Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdf               vfat        102182        0    102182   0% /mnt
```

If you didn't create a filesystem, or you don't know what it is then you may be able to identify it using the [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command

On the vfat disk above

```
file -sL /dev/sdf
/dev/sdf: x86 boot sector, mkdosfs boot message display, code offset 0x3c, OEM-ID "   mkdosfs", sectors/cluster 4, root entries 512, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/FAT 200, heads 16, sectors 204800 (volumes > 32 MB) , serial number 0x75525ae1, unlabeled, FAT (16 bit)
```

On the same disk after mkfs to ext4

```
File -sL
/dev/sdf: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=8d50d025-c6df-4b9e-9e8e-9ed5538062ca (extents) (huge files)
```

It seems that fsck will also give information about the filesystem type if it recognises it

```
fsck -N /def/sdf
[/sbin/fsck.vfat (1) -- /dev/sdf] fsck.vfat /dev/sdf

mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdf
fsck -N /dev/sdf
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sdf] fsck.ext4 /dev/sdf
```

If all that fails then chances are you don't have a filesystem on your disk so make one before mounting it with [mkfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs)